# ¿Cómo saber que error tiene mi script php alojado en un servidor remoto?

Tags: mysql, servidor, php7, phpmailer, cpanel

Hola a todos y gracias a los que comenten sugerencias para resolver este problema.

Tengo una estructura de archivos desarrollada con `php` para enviar emails, la tengo alojada en mi servidor local y la acabo de colgar en mi servidor remoto, esta estructura trabaja con `PHPMailer` y posee un `crud` de `mysql` nada del otro mundo.

En mi servidor local funciona perfectamente, pero al colgarla al servidor remoto no funciona, y no se, cómo saber exactamente cual es el error que tiene en el servidor para corregirlo. ¿Que puedo hacer para saberlo?

Dejare mi `index` para que lo revisen y si es un error de sintaxis editarlo.

Gracias por su atención, aquí está el `index.php`.

```html
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

require_once 'models/conexion.php';
require_once 'config/smtp.php';
require_once 'controllers/mailSend.php';
require_once 'models/ModelCrud.php';
require_once 'controllers/templateEmail.php';

require 'ext/PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'ext/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'ext/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$plantilla = new CrudModel();

/*Obtenemos los Usuarios*/
$usuarios = $plantilla->getDatos('select * from wp_user_register');

foreach ($usuarios as $key => $value) {

    $dateNow = date("Y-m-d");
    $dateEnd = date($value['date_now']);

    if ($dateEnd <= $dateNow) {
        $SendMsg = new MailSend();
        $post = $SendMsg->getPost('117');
        try {

            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

            $temp = new smtp();
            $smtp = $temp->smtpConfig($mail);

            $html = new templateEmail();
            $body = $html->template($post[0], $post[1]);

            $SendMsg->sendMail($smtp, $body, $value['email'], $value['name']);
            $SendMsg->updateWeek($value['weeks'], $value['date_now'], $value['post_actual'], $value['id']);

        } catch (Exception $th) {
            echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Chequea el log de apache2 esta ubicado en /var/log/apache2/

Comment: Gracias ya estoy revisando los registros, si deja algunos rastros del error, voy a revisarlo, agradecido por la sugerencia.

Comment: intenta algo como `tail -f -n300 /var/log/apache2/error.log` una vez que tengas eso intenta nuevamente enviar el correo

Comment: Hola @max si estas usando un servidor cpanel tienes que entrar en la administración y habilitar los error porque por defecto están deshabilitados lo puedes encontrar en **MultiPHP INI Editor** el te muestra en pantalla el error como si fuera un servidor de desarrollo. Gracias

Comment: Yoel Gracias por la sugerencia, ya la aplique, el rastro de los errores con el  MultiPHP INI Editor en que directorio los almacena?

Comment: Hice lo que me mencionaron ambos y conseguí donde se imprimen los errores de MultiPHP INI Editor, corregí todos los errores que me arrojaba, y aún así sigue sin funcionar.. Cualquier otra sugerencia es bienvenida